# How to get a document on Sharepoint by its unique ID?

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I am trying to achieve the following using the Sharepoint Client Object Model (CSOM) on a Sharepoint Online Instance:

- Perform a keyword query on the entire side
- Store some field value which uniquely identifies a search result (a row in the `SharepointResultTable` returned by the query
- Retrieve the same information as provided in the row of the result table at a later point or somewhere else (this is when I don't have the result table anymore) using this stored field value.

In pseudo code:

```
var results = Sharepoint.GetSearchResults("Keyword");
var specificItem = results[2];
var itemId = sepcificItem.UniqueId;
Store(itemId);
```

And later:

```
var itemId = LoadItemId();
var item = Sharepoint.GetItem(itemId);
```

The querying part is working fine, I get a search result table offering lots of field values for each result, such as different URLs and also unique identifiers, titles, etc.

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext(SharepointUri);
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(SharepointUserName, GetSecureString(SharepointPassword));
var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
keywordQuery.QueryText = keyword;
var searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
var sharepointResultTable = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var resultRow in sharepointResultTable.Value[0].ResultRows)
{
    var path = (string) resultRow["ServerRedirectedURL"];
    var id = Guid.Parse((string) resultRow["UniqueId"]);        
}
```

The part I am missing now is: **Which value(s) should I store for a result row and how can I perform an *efficient* query based on this data to get the item later?** (Of course I could just perform a query with the same keyword again, but as I know the id or whatever I've stored, there must be more efficient ways. Also, the item might not be a result of the former keyword anymore because it might have changed).

I've tried this, using the id in the result table column 'UniqueId':

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext(SharepointUri);
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(SharepointUserName, GetSecureString(SharepointPassword));
var file = clientContext.Web.GetFileById(location);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
return true;
```

It doesn't work, though:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException:
>   The property or field 'Name' has not been initialized. It has not been
>   requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be
>   explicitly requested.

and honestly, I don't know what I'm doing here, because it's really hard to tell for me what the various Id's mean (DocId, WorkId, UniqueId, just to mention three...).

Can anybody with a little more Sharepoint experience tell me the way here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException:
>   The property or field 'Name' has not been initialized. It has not been
>   requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be
>   explicitly requested.

tells that client object (`File`) *has not been requested*. In order to request client object, [ClientRuntimeContext.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536388.aspx) and [ClientRuntimeContext.LoadQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientruntimecontext.loadquery.aspx) methods are intended.

**Examples**

```
//1. Retrieve File
var file = ctx.Web.GetFileById(id);
ctx.Load(file);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();


//2.Explicitly specify what properties (e.g. `Name`) to retrieve 
var file = ctx.Web.GetFileById(id);
ctx.Load(file, f=>f.Name);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

From another hand, since SharePoint Search Query API returns results across site collections, you need to consider to specify the proper url for `ClientContext` in order to retrieve `File`, for example:

```
using (var ctx = GetContext(webUri, userName, password))
{

     var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(ctx) {QueryText = queryText};
     var searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(ctx);
     var resultTables = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     foreach (var resultRow in resultTables.Value[0].ResultRows)
     {
          var itemWebUri = new Uri((string)resultRow["SPWebUrl"]); //<- get web url of item
          var itemId = Guid.Parse((string)resultRow["UniqueId"]);


          using (var curCtx = GetContext(itemWebUri, userName, password))
          {
              var file = curCtx.Web.GetFileById(itemId);
              curCtx.Load(file, f => f.Name);
              curCtx.ExecuteQuery();
              Console.WriteLine(file.Name);     
          }        
     }
}
```

where

```
    public static ClientContext GetContext(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
    {
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (var ch in password) securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
        return new ClientContext(webUri) { Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword) };
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Vadim!! Exactly what I needed and it worked right away!

Comment: Hey Vadim, which version of SharePoint are you using? SP Online? When I add Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll (15) to my solution the method is not found at all. When I use 16 version Visual Studio seems to know the function, but when I run ExecuteQuery I receive a method not found exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Andreas, I've verified this example against CSOM SDK v16 (SharePoint Online)